# Let $H\leq G$. If $g\in G$, show that $gHg^{-1}=\left \{ g^{-1}hg:h\in H,g\in G \right \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If $g\in G$, show that $gHg^{-1}=\left \{ g^{-1}hg:h\in H,g\in G \right \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Proof: Since $e,e^{-1}\in G$, then $e^{-1}he\in gHg^{-1}$, and so $gHg^{-1}\neq \varnothing$.

Let $g^{-1}h_{1}g,\;\; g^{-1}h_{2}g\in gHg^{-1}$. Since $H$ is a subgroup, then $h_{1}h_{2}^{-1},\;\; h_{2}^{-1}\in H$. Then $g^{-1}h_{1}g\cdot (g^{-1}h_{2}g)^{-1}=g^{-1}h_{1}g\cdot g^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}g=g^{-1}gh_{1}h_{2}^{-1}g^{-1}g=eh_{1}h_{2}^{-1}e=h_{1}h_{2}^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$. Then $gHg^{-1} \leq G$. $\square$

Comment: Why is $HK$ closed?

Comment: **Please ask *one* question at a time.**

Comment: @numericalorange: The title of your question contains statement that is false in general. Care to correct it?

Comment: @Tortoise Should I say instead "prove or disprove" and state that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$?

Comment: numericalorange No, you should ask one question, such that the title summarizes the question in the body.  DO NOT "double dip": trying to ask two separate questions in one post.

Comment: @amWhy Thank you, this has already been brought to my attention. May I ask where on the site does it say no "double-dipping" though? I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality $g^{-1}h_{1}g\cdot g^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}g=g^{-1}gh_{1}h_{2}^{-1}g^{-1}g$ is wrong for non-abelian groups in general.

Comment: Yes, I realized that now. Thank you for pointing that out. How do I show $(g_{1}^{-1}h_{1}g_{1})(g_{2}^{-1}h_{2}g_{2})^{-1}=g_{1}^{-1}h_{1}g_{1}g_{2}^{-1}h_{2}^{-1}g_{2} \in gHg^{-1}$?

Comment: We have $g^{-1}h_1g(g^{-1}h_2g)^{-1}=g^{-1}h_1gg^{-1}h_2^{-1}g$. Can you do the rest, @numericalorange?

Comment: I don't know where you got $g_1, g_2$ from.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer using the tick, @numericalorange.